# Data output from the database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a select and I want to output data from the DB

```
            <select class="select-css" name="title" required="">
                <option selected="" value="" disabled="">Выберите сервер</option>
                @foreach($guilds as $guild)
                    <option value="{{$guild->id}}">{{$guild->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

In CreateController I wrote this

```
$guilds = User::with('guilds')->get('id') === Auth::user()->id;
```

I have a UserGuild database

```
class UserGuild extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
    public function guild(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Guild::class);
    }
```

```
        Schema::create('user_guilds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('guild_id')->nullable();
            $table->index('user_id','user_guild_user_idx');
            $table->index('guild_id','user_guild_guild_idx');
            $table->foreign('user_id','user_guild_user_fk')->on('users')->references('id');
            $table->foreign('guild_id','user_guild_guild_fk')->on('guilds')->references('id');
```

And I have such a mistake

```
ErrorException
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, bool given (View: C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\site-rts\resources\views\main\server\create.blade.php)
```

I need to output to select what is in the `User Guide` database, but at the same time where `{{$guild->name}}`and `value` were were values from the `Guild` database

I also tried using foreach, but it doesn't suit me for further work.

```
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    @foreach($user->guilds as $guild)
                        @if(Auth::user()->id === $user->id)
                              <option value="{{$guild->id}}">{{$guild->name}}</option>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
```

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow. just to be sure, you wanted to find `guild`s with id matching user's id? your query returns boolean instead of collection. so, i want to be sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: When logging in via Discord, I have values added to the User Guide table. And I need to output only those guilds that the user consists of

Comment: @BagusTesa Hi, right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the model and migration is correct, the problem lies in query which in this case returning `boolean` instead of `collection`, and then foreach in the blade view get passed `boolean` as an argument instead of `collection` because of this it will throw an error.

So instead using these condition `=== Auth::user()->id;`, you can use where method to get data from database that correspond with `id` you want.

```
$guild = User::with('guilds')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```